# How to get ride of the file extension in \currfilename

Tags: external-files, jobname, nameref

How to get ride of the file extension in `\currfilename`?

The `\jobname` would only give me the `name` without the `.tex`, which is fine. But that's not what I want if I am using `\input` or `\include`.

So `\currfilename` refers to the correct file I want in this case, but how to get ride of the `.tex`?

Thanks.

Comment: `\currfilebase`

Comment: @egreg You are more useful and effective then searching on Google! If you put this simple answer down, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package provides `\currfilebase` as can be checked on page 2 of the documentation of `currfile`:

[image]

Comment: Which package you mean?

Comment: @Sigur currfile, the package the OP uses, but as there is no MWE I edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: I suspected it, but the OP does not mention any package (at least, explicitly). Thanks.

Comment: It can be used without loading the package. (Or maybe it was loaded via a different package)